# Error Custom page edit

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, error-messages

I have created a custom visual force page to override the standard page for edit a custom object "`Influencer__c`".

This is my page:

```
apex:page Standardcontroller="Influencer__c" id="Page" tabstyle="Contact">

script type="text/javascript"> 

 <apex:page Standardcontroller="Influencer__c" id="Page"  tabstyle="Contact">

  <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function openLookup(baseURL, width, modified, searchParam){
    var originalbaseURL = baseURL;
    var originalwidth = width;
    var originalmodified = modified;
    var originalsearchParam = searchParam;

    var lookupType = baseURL.substr(baseURL.length-3, 3);
    if (modified == '1') baseURL = baseURL + searchParam;

    var isCustomLookup = false;

    // Following "001" is the lookup type for Account object so change this as per your standard or custom object
    if(lookupType == "003"){

      var urlArr = baseURL.split("&");
      var txtId = '';
      if(urlArr.length > 2) {
        urlArr = urlArr[1].split('=');
        txtId = urlArr[1];
      }

      // Following is the url of Custom Lookup page. 
      baseURL = "/apex/CustomInfluencerLookup?accplanid={!Influencer__c.Account_Plan__c}&txt=" + txtId;

      // Following is the id of apex:form control "myForm". 
      baseURL = baseURL + "&frm=" + escapeUTF("{!$Component.myForm}");
      if (modified == '1') {
        baseURL = baseURL + "&lksearch=" + searchParam;
      }

      // Following is the ID of inputField that is the lookup to be customized as custom lookup
      if(txtId.indexOf('mycontact') > -1 ){
        isCustomLookup = true;
      }
    }


    if(isCustomLookup == true){
      openPopup(baseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+width+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    }
    else {
      if (modified == '1') originalbaseURL = originalbaseURL + originalsearchParam;
      openPopup(originalbaseURL, "lookup", 350, 480, "width="+originalwidth+",height=480,toolbar=no,status=no,directories=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,scrollable=no", true);
    } 
  }
</script>



<apex:sectionHeader title="{!$ObjectType.Influencer__c.label}" subtitle="{!Influencer__c.name}"/>
    <apex:pageBlock title="{!$ObjectType.Influencer__c.label} Detail" mode="edit">
 <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:form>

            <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}"/>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" immediate="true" value="Cancel"/>

        </apex:form> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>


         <apex:form>
         <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Information" columns="2"> 

            <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Name}"/>
          <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Account_Plan__c}" required="true"/>
          <apex:inputField id="mycontact" value="{!Influencer__c.Contact__c}" required="true"/> 
            <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Type__c}" required="false"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.CCS_Role__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.IMPACT__c}" required="false"/> 
           <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Top_Goals__c}" required="false"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Attitude_towards_QT__c}" required="false"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Contact_Risk_Profile__c}" required="false"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Time_Spent__c}" required="false"/>
           <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Has_Power__c}" required="false"/> 
           <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.Has_Budget__c}" required="false"/>
            <apex:inputField value="{!Influencer__c.QT_Exec__c}" required="false"/>

        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>


       <apex:pageBlockSection showHeader="false" columns="2">
            <apex:outputField value="{!Influencer__c.CreatedById}"/>
            <apex:outputField value="{!Influencer__c.LastModifiedById}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
   </apex:pageBlock>

 </apex:page>
```

When I press the button SAVE the new informations are not saved.

Where am I wrong?

Any problem with code problem in the code's page or is it because i have overridden the button?

Please help me.

Thank you very much.

BR

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Influencer.Account_Plan__c
```

I see above following has been used.

`instead __c` must be appended

`Influencer__c.Account_Plan__c` must be used in this case.

Comment: Please can you helpme again? When i press the button SAVE the new informations are not saved.
Where am i wrong?
have i a problem in the code's page or is it because i have overridden the button?
 I have updated my code in the question.
Thank you very much.

Comment: please avoid multiple forms in page

Comment: Thank you very much Mohith! you are great, I hope to become as good as you! Thanks again.

Comment: @Enry Thanks !Glad that it helped.Always love to contribute and help on this site